# How to integrate Hasura with Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase-authentication, hasura

Does anyone here have experienced Hasura graphql ?
I started exploring @postgrest to fulfill my serverless needs, but I end up dumping it since its hard to make its authentication. Just last two day I learned that I can do phone number authentication with Firebase Authentication with my reactjs App.
Then I look back at my database solution, I learned that Apollo graphql and also Hasura may solve my database needs. I have no Idea whether I can integrate my phone auth so that It produce jwt and can be used in Hasura / Apollo maybe?
Cut story short, is Hasura famous among us here ? What do you guys use for Graphql authentication ? Can it integrate with Firebase authentication ?

any suggestions much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I've integrated `GraphQL + Firebase Auth` with both frontend and backend system before. I didn't use `Hasura`, just a normal Apollo GraphQL, but the concept should be the same. Hope it can help

**Frontend phone authentication**

In this example the frontend was developed using Flutter.
Get `firebaseToken` from `FirebaseAuth`, passing to `login Mutation` with input firebaseToken.  This login Mutation must return `JWT token`.
Store this JWT token securely in your app

```
await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
        verificationCompleted:
            (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
          final UserCredential cr =
              await FirebaseAuth.instance
                  .signInWithCredential(credential);
          final String firebaseToken =
              await cr.user!.getIdToken();
          final QueryResult qe = await runMutation(
                  {"firebaseToken": firebaseToken})
              .networkResult!;
          final String jwt =
              Login$Mutation.fromJson(qe.data!)
                  .login
                  .jwtToken;

          ...
        },
        ...
      );
```

**GraphQL**

```
mutation Login($firebaseToken: String!) {
  login(input: { firebaseToken: $firebaseToken }) {
    jwtToken
  }
}
```

**Schema GQL**

```
type Mutation {
      login(input: LoginInput!): Login! }

input LoginInput {
  firebaseToken: String!
}

type Login {
  jwtToken: String!
}
```

**Backend Auth Resolver**

In this example, backend was developed using NestJS (node.js). First create Auth resolver with login Mutation that accept `firebaseToken`. This login Mutation need to verify Id Token (Using `Firebase Admin SDK`). After verify you can get `decodedToken`, either phone number or email depending on your Firebase project authentication settings. Use this info to create new user if not exist. Return JWT token using payload e:g `{id: user.id}`

```
@Mutation(() => LoginDTO)
  async login(
    @Args('input', { type: () => LoginInput }) input: LoginInput
  ): Promise<LoginDTO> {
    const decodedToken = await this.firebaseAuth.app
      .auth()
      .verifyIdToken(input.firebaseToken);
    const number = (
      decodedToken.firebase.identities.phone[0] as string
    ).substring(1);
    const user = await this.passengerService.findOrCreateUserWithMobileNumber(
      number
    );
    const payload = { id: user.id };
    return {
      jwtToken: this.jwtService.sign(payload),
    };
  }
```

Comment: I think I should use Apollo since I'm using NextJS as well.